# Finding articulation points using DFS and the bi-components algorithm

Tags: algorithm, theory, depth-first-search

I am having trouble implementing (not code) DFS incorporating the bi-components algorithm to find articulation points in a graph, the algorithm was presented in my computer science lecture and I didn't grasp the implementation. (Just to clarify I know how to implement DFS) Let me explain: we are given a graph and we have to perform a DFS to find all the articulation points, using back numbers and the DFS number. My major problem is finding the back number of each node, using the given algorithm.

We were given a tutorial as an exercise to implement the algorithm, I done it but I have no idea if it is correct. Could someone please check that I have done it correctly and if possible correct me. The tutorial question is as follows

> Use the algorithm done in class to do a
>   depth-first search tree of the algorithm. For each vertex find:
>
> • the dfs-number
>
> • the back number
>
> • whether it is an articulation point
>   [image]
>   The algorithm and My solution is:
>   [image]
>   Thanks. Hope someone can help

Comment: Why do you think that J should be an articulation point?  It isn't one. B is not an articulation point either.

Comment: Because according to the articulation point condition 15>14, thus it is an articulation point, however I know this is not true because if we remove J, it doesn't disconnect the graph

Comment: You have dfs-time = 14 and back-number=12. It's not articulation point according to your algorithm and it's not an articulation point indeed.

Comment: Yes I see my error over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You algorithm is almost correct. The only case which is handled improperly is the root: a root is an articulation point if and only if it has two or more children in the dfs tree.

Comment: Thanks, with regards to the root in this case it is an articulation since it does have two children, so why is it handled improperly?

Comment: @amine Two children in the dfs-tree, not the original graph. If there is only one child (which is the case for the graph from your question), it's not an articulation point, even though Back(w) >= dfs-time(root) for any child.